# Insert new object into Array Attribute in document in mongodb using mgo.v2

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, go, mgo

I am using mgo.v2 mongodb driver to manupulation data with mongodb.I have data strucure as follow json

```
  "configs": [
        {
          "configid":1,
          "id": 0,
          "widgets": [
            {
              "position": 1,
              "type": 1,
              "class": "normal green",
              "metricid": 5
            },
            {
              "position": 2,
              "type": 1,
              "class": "normal blue",
              "metricid": 6
            }
         ]
      }
    ]
```

I have created `configs` collection by using above json structure.

```
err2 := session.DB("db").C("configs").Insert(&config)
```

but.In my case, I want add new item to widgets array to this configid. it is kind of object like this,

```
    {
      "position": 3,
      "type": 1,
      "class": "normal red",
      "metricid": 7
    }
```

What is the best way to adding this object into widgets array in paticular configid in mongodb? I am using mgo.v2 mongodb driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the update method to add the array element using the **[`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)** operator. For example:

```
session.DB("db").C("configs").Update(
    bson.M{"configid": 1}, 
    bson.M{"$push": bson.M{"widgets": widget}}
)
```